# Drawbacks/Limitations of short WaitForSingleObject time

Tags: c++, winapi

Are there any drawbacks or possible limitations of using `WaitForSingleObject` with a short wait time (~10ms) compared to an infinite wait time?

My application architecture is really only going to work by having a short wait time due to a design issue.

Comment: What sort of drawbacks are you envisioning?

Comment: Missing a windows message/event because its not listening for a short time as the function returns and the other while loop logic occurs. Drawbacks of inefficiency as the function returns every 10ms as opposed to waiting for messages

Comment: @JakeM: You probably have bigger design issues, given those concerns. Messages are **not** lost like this, Windows has a message **queue**. Also, you'd need `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` if you need to wait simultaneously on messages and a thread handle.

Comment: You aren't going to miss anything. And yes, you are using the wrong function. `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` is what you need. Maybe. Alternatively you could just not wait at all and have the thread send you a message when it is done. I think it very likely that your entire approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

10 milliseconds is short enough that any other program having a minor hiccup could affect the result of your program. That is *very* rarely the intention.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate on what effect it could have? And what do you mean by 'very rarely the intention' do you mean we very rarely intend to use waitforsingleobject with such a short time?

Comment: @JakeM: Obviously the result is return S_SUCCESS instead of S_APP_EXIT. What that means, well, it's your code. And it's very rare that you want **another random program** to affect you in this way. Remember, you give up your time slice, and you may not get another time slice within 10 milliseconds.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11387216)

Comment: @kazemakase: You should read the question again. It asks for drawbacks of the technique. Because "random other programs influencing your program" is a drawback, this is an answer.

Comment: @MSalters - seems you are right. The question asks for drawbacks, indeed.